# Pandas count same value of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a datframe like this

```
df
    i    j
0   A    C
1   A    F
2   B    A
3   C    D
4   D    E
```

I would like something like this

```
df
    i    count
0   A      3 
1   B      1
2   C      2
3   D      2
4   E      1
5   F      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it just:

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```